# The best way to keep multiple images in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design, image-uploading

### I use Ruby on Rails with postgresql and I see two options:

- Model has field image, which type of is json (and keep them as array).
- Model has_many_and_belongs_to related model like "Image".

**Which of these two is more preferable?**

> I consider performance as the first and convenience as the second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would ask my self this question.
Is the image only relates to 1 model?

If, it will only be related to 1 model, like profile picture. Then, it will be best fit for first approach

> Model has field image, which type of is json (and keep them as array).

If the image will be used for multiple models like emoji or letter_avatar. Then, it will be fit on the second approach

> Model has_many_and_belongs_to related model like "Image".

Performance wise, it will be better in the first approach. You don't have to spend resource to fetch related models.